# client-go var set from function which returns empty interface; can't seem to use it though("obj is not a type")...need clarification

Tags: go, client-go

So, I'm writing a client-go app and took some code as boilerplate, but I'm struggling with a portion of code:

Here's what I'm using for boilerplate: https://www.codetd.com/en/article/7292846

and I'm tweaking to my needs. Here's my code:

```
// syncToStdout is the business logic of the controller. In this controller it simply prints
// information about the secret to stdout. In case an error happened, it has to simply return the error.
// The retry logic should not be part of the business logic.
func (c *Controller) syncToStdout(key string) error {
    obj, exists, err := c.indexer.GetByKey(key)
    if err != nil {
        klog.Errorf("Fetching object with key %s from store failed with %v", key, err)
        return err
    }

    if !exists {
        klog.Infof("delete? %+v", obj)
        // Below we will warm up our cache with a Secret, so that we will see a delete action for one secret
        klog.Infof("Secret %s does not exist anymore, but not delering from AMZ", key)
    } else {

        // This is where I am stuck...
        // I need to dereference `obj` to exact annotations...
        // But this doesn't work.
        // `obj` is an empty interface
        objectMeta := obj{
            &v1.Secret{
                ObjectMeta: metav1.ObjectMeta{},
            },
        }

        syncEnabled := objectMeta.Annotations[operatorName+"/sync-enabled"]
        acmEnabled := objectMeta.Annotations[operatorName+"/acm-enabled"]
        asmEnabled := objectMeta.Annotations[operatorName+"/asm-enabled"]

        //obj{v1.Secret{TypeMeta:v1.TypeMeta}
        klog.Infof("add/update? %#v", obj)

        // Note that you also have to check the uid if you have a local controlled resource, which
        // is dependent on the actual instance, to detect that a Secret was recreated with the same name
        klog.Infof("Sync/Add/Update for Secret %s", obj.(*v1.Secret).GetName())
    }
    return nil
}
```

OK, so I'm working with K8s Secrets here. I found the following:

https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/issues/297 which led to
https://github.com/tamalsaha/workqueue-demo/blob/4012bea01dca4987de51a78c2edb529ae96fdbbf/main.go

but this isn't necessarily answering my question. If `Indexer` is returning an obj which is of type `empty interface`, I'm assuming it's not really nil? Empty interfaces elude me. I see them used often but I don't fully understand how they work. I can't reference the stuff inside this empty interface, though, and I'm not sure why.

IDE view

=[image: IDE view]

empty interface hint to obj creation states "obj is not a type," and this seems to be an empty interface returned from the function `Indexer.GetByKey(key)`
[image: empty interface hint to obj creation]

but I can fill in all fields so is it really empty?
[image: but I can fill all fields so is it really empty?]

so like it's empty but it's not nil?
[image: so like it's empty but it's not nil?]

And there don't seem to be any methods attached to it
[image: no functions]

so what's most confusing is that if I print it with `%#v` I get an entire object and one which contains the data I'm seeking:

(note that this has been scrubbed)

```
I1208 12:13:53.365680   98945 kubernetes-controller.go:67] 
add/update? &v1.Secret{TypeMeta:v1.TypeMeta{Kind:"", APIVersion:""}, 
ObjectMeta:v1.ObjectMeta{Name:"some-cert", GenerateName:"", 
Namespace:"cert-manager", SelfLink:"", UID:"ac3072ea-95fa-4b99-b284-b9755b1859c4", ResourceVersion:"xxxxx2721", Generation:0,
 CreationTimestamp:time.Date(2022, time.March, 28, 11, 24, 56, 0, time.Local), DeletionTimestamp:<nil>, DeletionGracePeriodSeconds:(*int64)(nil), Labels:map[string]string(nil),
 Annotations:map[string]string{"cert-manager.io/allow-direct-injection":"true"}, OwnerReferences:[]v1.OwnerReference(nil), Finalizers:[]string(nil), ManagedFields:
[]v1.ManagedFieldsEntry{v1.ManagedFieldsEntry{Manager:"thingy", 
Operation:"Update", APIVersion:"v1", Time:time.Date(2022, 
time.March, 28, 11, 24, 56, 0, time.Local), FieldsType:"FieldsV1",
 FieldsV1:(*v1.FieldsV1)(0x1400000ec78), Subresource:""}}}, 
Immutable:(*bool)(nil), Data:map[string][]uint8{"ca.crt":[]uint8{<REDACTED>}}, StringData:map[string]string(nil), 
Type:"Opaque"}
```

the `Annotations` are what I'm in need of grabbing. So how come go reflection can retrieve the data, but I can't reference it? Do I need to write a bunch of reflection code to get to what I need?

Answer (score 0):

OK! Finally figured this out.

The function returns an empty interface as a type. So I need to do a type assertion to propagate the data into the variable.

```
    } else {
        obj := obj.(*v1.Secret)   // <=== this is the "magic" line

        annotations := obj.ObjectMeta.Annotations

        syncEnabled := annotations[operatorName+"/sync-enabled"]
        cmEnabled := annotations[operatorName+"/acm-enabled"]
        smEnabled := annotations[operatorName+"/asm-enabled"]

        klog.Infof("add/update? %#v", obj)

        // Note that you also have to check the uid if you have a local controlled resource, which
        // is dependent on the actual instance, to detect that a Secret was recreated with the same name
        klog.Infof("Sync/Add/Update for Secret %s", obj.(*v1.Secret).GetName())
        //      }
    }
    return nil
}
```

I can probably do this more efficiently somewhere else, but this was what I needed. And I also see that the original coder used this in the code and I simply didn't understand.

Had I been paying closer attention, I'd have seen the reference to the answer in `klog.Infof("Sync/Add/Update for Secret %s", obj.(*v1.Secret).GetName())`

Oh well.